# HTTP header provided in browser address bar

Tags: http, url, browser, http-headers

Is it possible to provide HTTP header in browser's address bar?

e.g.

```
http://webpage.com/somepage.html  [header1:value, header2:value]
```

My aim is testing different headers, but without scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use POSTMAN for it... It will allow you to send request of the type you want GET/POST/DELETE/PUT with whatever headers you expect to have.

For simple testing and checking of what content you get, you could select GET request and set the headers.

Here's a [guide](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/) to using it

Comment: Thanks for tip. It's great, but it requires to sign in to use it :-(

Comment: Ohh... I believe you could skip that... or else simply signup... its free